# What's the difference between closure parameters and the 'use' keyword?

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

This has got me very confused and I can't seem to find an answer to this question. A clear and simple clarification would be nice.

Comment: I think you have chosen the wrong answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A closure is a function that is evaluated in its own environment, which has one or more bound variables that can be accessed when the function is called. They come from the functional programming world, where there are a number of concepts in play. Closures are like lambda functions, but smarter in the sense that they have the ability to interact with variables from the outside environment of where the closure is defined.

The use() keyword let's you import variables from outside the function environment, inside the function. Variables to be imported from the outside environment are specified in the use clause of the closure function definition. By default, they are passed by value. So let's say the function has no parameters, but you wan't it to use a variable you already have.

```
$string = "Hello World!";
$closure = function() use ($string) { echo $string; };
```

This is useful when you need to create a function what must be used as callback somewhere else, and can only have defined parameters. The use() keyword let's you use other variables in addition to the ones you pass as function arguements. For example on the php.net example: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
public function getTotal($tax)
    {
        $total = 0.00;

        $callback =
            function ($quantity, $product) use ($tax, &$total)
            {
                $pricePerItem = constant(__CLASS__ . "::PRICE_" .
                    strtoupper($product));
                $total += ($pricePerItem * $quantity) * ($tax + 1.0);
            };

        array_walk($this->products, $callback);
        return round($total, 2);
    }
```

$callback must only have two parameters, because array_walk will only allow that much:

> Typically, funcname takes on two parameters. The array parameter's
>   value being the first, and the key/index second.

So what can we do? We call `use()` to add other variables that are not the $callback's scope, but in scope of the environment it is being called in.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me. How is it any different from `$closure = function($string) { echo $string; };`?

Comment: @Seralize: Sorry, updated my example. Basically, some functions in PHP allow callbacks(like array_walk, array_map, etc that have predefined parameters. In these instances, you can call use() to add other variables that otherwise would not be possible to use in a callback.

Comment: That makes sense. So the `use()` keyword is basically just a way to import variables into a closure without messing up the "parameter flow", since parameters that are not set will give an error?

Comment: @Seralize: Yes. It let's you add more context to the function without changing the parameters.

Comment: In one way it seems pointless but in another there will always be times where such small things can help settle a problem. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @Seralize: It's the whole point of a *closure*. It has nothing to do with "parameter flow" or whatever. What you gave later is a function that always outputs its argument, which isn't interesting. With the expression from earlier, we can make a function that prints "foo", or a function that prints "bar", or anything else; and we do this without actually writing different functions; that one line of code, each time it is run, will create a function with new behavior (depending on the value of the captured variable) -- as if you manually wrote separate functions for them. That is the difference.

Answer (score 26):

The `use statement` captures the **variable** at the time the **closure function  is created**.

Regular function arguments capture the **value** when the function is **called**.

Note that I differentiated between `variable` and `value` there.

```
function makeAnAdder($leftNum) {
    // Notice that *each time* this makeAnAdder function gets called, we 
    // create and then return a brand new closure function.
    $closureFunc = function($rightNum) use ($leftNum) {
        return $leftNum + $rightNum;
    };

    return $closureFunc;
}

$add5to = makeAnAdder(5);
$add7to = makeAnAdder(7);

echo $add5to(10); // 15
echo $add7to(1); // 8
```

If there were a way to inspect the, um, "source code" of the `$add5to` function, it would look like this:

```
function($rightNum) {
    return 5 + $rightNum;
}
```

I guess you could kinda say the value of `$leftNum` got remembered by the closure function.

I want to further emphasize that the `use statement` allows you to maintain a `reference` to a **variable**, and not just a copy of the **value** that the variable had at some point. To clarify my idea: think of a variable as being a little box, which can contain a single value at any instant in time, and that value can be changed. And, you can make another variable point to that box, so that you can update the value in the box, or read the current value in it.

Normally, a local variable that is created within a function ceases to exist after the function returns. But, a closure function can maintain a reference to that variable, and cause that local variable to live on even after the function returns - and this is the true power of closure functions. It lets you mimic certain behaviors of a class (instance variables), with just a tiny bit of code.

Here's a more advanced example, that might take some deep thinking to understand the fine details of the behavior.

```
function makeBankAccount() {
    // Each time this makeBankAccount func is called, a new, totally
    // independent local variable named $balance is created.
    $balance = 0;

    // Also, on each call we create 2 new closure functions, $modifyBalance, and $getBalance
    // which will hold a reference to the $balance variable even after makeBankAccount returns.
    $modifyBalance = function($amount) use (&$balance) {
        $balance += $amount;
    };

    $getBalance = function() use (&$balance) {
        return $balance;
    };

    // return both closure functions.
    return ['modifyBalance' => $modifyBalance, 'getBalance' => $getBalance];
}

// Let's prove that bank1 works by adding 5 to the balance by using the first
// function, then using the other function to get the balance
// from the same internal variable.
$bank1 = makeBankAccount();
$bank1['modifyBalance'](5);
echo $bank1['getBalance'](); // 5 - it works.

// Now let's make another bank to prove that it has it's own independent internal $balance variable.
$bank2 = makeBankAccount();
$bank2['modifyBalance'](10);
echo $bank2['getBalance'](); // 10 - as expected. It would have printed 15 if bank2 shared a variable with bank1.

// Let's test bank1 one more time to be sure that bank2 didn't mess with it.
echo $bank1['getBalance'](); // 5 - still 5, as expected.
```

You may have noticed I used the [reference operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) `&` in this example. If you're not yet familiar with them yet, just know that References are known to be hard to understand. Although, I hope this post mostly makes sense by itself.

Comment: That's a good point you got there. It took me a while to understand how the `$rightnum` parameter got called but it makes sense now.

Comment: Ya, some of this stuff is really difficult to understand because there's so many points of indirection and evaluation. I'll add a clarification that hopefully helps.